Does Cytoscape use a licensed version of Java JRE?
Using Cytoscape requires the use of Java JRE.  Where can I find documentation that Cytoscape uses a licensed version of Java?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I need to provide proof that Cytoscape uses a licensed version of Java JRE.

Cytoscape is shipped with the Temurin OpenJDK from Adoptium, which is licensed under GPL version 2 with the classpath exception.  For more information see the FAQ

In the installation section of the Cytoscape manual, there is information about the versions of Java that are compatible with Cytoscape:

Cytoscape requires Java 17.

We recommend a 64 bit Java Runtime Environment (JRE) such as OpenJDK 17.

While Cytoscape versions prior to v3.2 run on Java 6, Oracle and other JVM suppliers have dropped Java 6 support. Consequently, Cytoscape v3.2 and later don’t support Java 6. With v3.3, we also dropped support for Java 7, and with the release of Cytoscape v3.8 we dropped support for Java 8. With v3.10, we droppped support for Java 11, for the same reason.


For additional information, select the Release Notes button on the Cytoscape website.

